# Don't skip ansible 1.9 role if previous failed.

Tags: ansible

I have the following ansible playbook:

```
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - start_measurement_script
    - run_calculations
    - stop_measurement_script
    - gather_logs
```

I would like to execute role `stop_measurement_script` even if `run_calculations`fails. However, `gather_logs` role should not be executed. Role `stop_measurement_script` contains only one task. Is there any way to accomplish this?

I am using ansible 1.9.4 so I can't use `blocks` feature from Ansible 2.0. I've seen `always_run` clause but it seems that its name is misleading and it is used in different scenarios.

Comment: Do you need `start_measurement_script` and `stop_measurement_script` to be a role ? Could you add the actions in `run_calculations/tasks/start_measurement_script.yml` and then catch the error inside run_calculations, include `stop_measurement_script.yml` and then `fail:` ?

Comment: I don't want to modify `run_calculations` because it is used in multiple playbooks and only in this specific one, measurement script is used. In other playbooks I want to skip next roles if `run_calculations` failed.

Comment: If that is the only case, you can add a flag in the modified `run_calculations` that will allow you to include the extra playbooks, for example `enable_measuremnt` that will always default to false thorugh `run_calculations/defaults/main.yml` and from within that playbook you can set `vars: enable_measurement: true`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `ignore_errors: True` to your step.

You can also add a step to provide a true failure following the step.

Read more at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure